# Postfix unknown command

Tags: postfix, smtp

I'm running two milters on my current postfix installation.  I'm noticing that, from one particular client, they are sending an invalid command consisting of the first 3 letters of their domain name.  When postfix sees this, it causes my milters to exit out.

How can I proceed past this?

I've seen this on the postfix documentation, but am not sure how to apply it:

```
milter_unknown_command_macros (default: see "postconf -d" output)
The macros that are sent to version 3 or higher Milter (mail filter) applications after an unknown SMTP command. See MILTER_README for a list of available macro names and their meanings.

This feature is available in Postfix 2.3 and later.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**smtpd_command_filter**](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_command_filter) to exclude these bogus commands:

In /etc/postfix/main.cf:

`smtpd_command_filter = pcre:/etc/postfix/bogus_commands`

And in /etc/postfix/bogus_commands:

`/[^ ]{3}/    NOOP`

You may have to test the regex to fit your needs.

There are no SMTP commands that consist of 3 letters :)

Comment: i like this. i'll give it a shot later today.

Comment: i'm not a pcre guy, but this is replacing ALL commands that I enter with NOOP

Comment: this seems to work:  /^[^ ]{3}\s.*/

Comment: Yeah sorry about that - you have to match the non-character after the three initial characters to guarantee that it's ONLY three characters ;)