# Postfix regex for smtpd_command_filter

Tags: postfix, regex, email-bounces, pcre

Some of my users are using Gmail to send mail to our domain (The mail server for which is hosted on a CentOS 5 machine with postfix). Sometimes, but not all the time, when they do, they get a bounceback similar to:

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: Mail Delivery Subsystem <mailer-daemon@googlemail.com>
Date: Mon, Aug 19, 2013 at 9:12 AM
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
To: user1@domain.com


Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

 user2@domain.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the       recipient domain domain.com by mail.domain.com. [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx].

The error that the other server returned was:
502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized

----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=gmail.com; s=;
    h=mime-version:sender:in-reply-to:references:date:message-id:subject
     :from:to:content-type;
    bh=...=;
    b=...==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with SMTP id ...;
 Mon, 19 Aug 2013 06:12:55 -0700 (PDT)
Sender: user1@gmail.com
Received: by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with HTTP; Mon, 19 Aug 2013 06:12:55 -0700 (PDT)
In-Reply-To: <...@mail.gmail.com>
References: <...@mail.gmail.com>
    <...@domain.com>
    <....gmail.com>
    <....gmail.com>
Date: Mon, 19 Aug 2013 09:12:55 -0400
X-Google-Sender-Auth: ...
Message-ID: <...@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: ...
From: <user1@domain.com>
To: <user2@domain.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=...
```

But the weird thing is, the mail still goes through...
Upon inspection of my maillogs, I see lines similar to:

```
Aug 19 9:12:36 domain postfix/smtpd[...]: connect from mail.google.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Aug 19 9:12:37 domain postfix/smtpd[...]: XXXX: mail.google.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Aug 19 9:12:37 domain postfix/smtpd[...]: warning: non-SMTP command from mail.google.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:         h=mime-version:sender:in-reply-to:references:date:message-id:subject
Aug 19 9:12:37 domain postfix/smtpd[...]: disconnect from mail.google.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
```

It appears as though my mail server is interpreting the "h=mime" line as a command.
After some research, I followed this thread:

```
http://serverfault.com/questions/379964/postfix-unknown-command/380248#380248
```

and I added the

```
smtpd_command_filter = pcre:/etc/postfix/bogus_commands
```

parameter to my /etc/postfix/main.cf file, then added some regex to the bogus_commands file to try and replace any command beginning with

```
h=mime
```

to

```
NOOP
```

But, none of the regex I've tried seems to be working.
I have tried:

```
/^.*h=mime.*$/\s NOOP  

preg_replace(^.*h=mime.*$, NOOP, )  

/.*h=mime.*/ NOOP
```

Can anyone help me find the proper syntax for the regex that I need for this to work? I'm not a regex expert by any means. I'm probably just doing something simple wrong. Any help you can provide is most appreciated.

Comment: How about this? preg_replace('/^.*h=mime.*$/', 'NOOP', )

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. After I added it to the bogus_commands file, I did a condrestart on postfix then tried telnet-ing into the mail server on port 25 and typing "h=mime" it replied "502 5.5.2 Error: Unknown Command". I believe that if the filter was working then it would respond "520 2.0.0 OK". But, I've never done this before.

Comment: can you try with this? postmap -q "string" pcre:/etc/postfix/filename

Comment: Same result. Maybe I should try reloading postfix instead of just a condrestart?

Comment: I think I may have found out something important. On the [man page](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_command_filter) for smtpd_command_filter, it says right at the bottom "available in postix 2.7". I, as it turns out, only have postfix 2.3.3. I'll update postfix and try again.

Comment: Oh yeah, that is important point, it won't work in 2.3.

Comment: I updated postfix to version 2.10.1 and I didn't even need the regex anymore. Everything is working fine now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my particular case, it turns out I was using an incorrect version of postfix to try and implement the smtpd_command_filter parameter. After updating postfix to the latest version, everything is working fine now.